# Long polling with kotlin coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, completable-future, long-polling

I found this repository at GitHub [Long Polling Redis](https://github.com/studerw/long-polling-redis/blob/master/src/main/java/com/studerw/appMsg/AppMsgHandler.java#L74)

So in spring boot, we can use a **deferred request** to hold the client request for several seconds ([AppMsgController.java#L72](https://github.com/studerw/long-polling-redis/blob/master/src/main/java/com/studerw/appMsg/AppMsgController.java#L72))

and it will send back to the client until the **deferred request** is filled with the result ([AppMsgHandler.java#L74](https://github.com/studerw/long-polling-redis/blob/master/src/main/java/com/studerw/appMsg/AppMsgHandler.java#L74)) or until it reaches the timeout.

I also notice this mechanism also can be implemented with **CompetableFuture** in java using **completeOnTimeout**.

But I wonder can we use something similar in Kotlin Coroutines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin coroutines there is the [`Deferred`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-deferred/index.html) type, which is similar to `CompletableFuture` in the sense that it represents a value that is not yet available but probably will be in the future (if no error occurs/exception is thrown). @Joffrey pointed out that there is also a [`CompletableDeferred`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-completable-deferred/index.html), which is even closer to `ComplatableFuture` enabling the user to manually call `complete` or `exceptionallyComplete`.

Deferreds can easily be created with the [`async`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/async.html) extension function on `CoroutineScope`. If you want to set a timeout, Kotlin has you covered with the [`withTimeout`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-timeout.html?query=suspend%20fun%20%3CT%3E%20withTimeout(timeMillis:%20Long,%20block:%20suspend%20CoroutineScope.()%20-%3E%20T):%20T) function that cancels the block of code after a given time.

Note that `withTimeout` should be inside `async` and not the other way around.

Take a look at this example: https://pl.kotl.in/uYe12ds7g

Comment: I believe `CompletableDeferred` would be more similar to `CompletableFuture` than `Deferred`, in the sense that you can manually complete it with a value or error

Answer (score 2):

As @Spitzbueb said, you could do something similar with `CompletableDeferred`.

However, if you don't need to support the `clear()` and `count()` methods, you could also probably simplify by replacing the `ConcurrentHashMap` with a simple `MutableSharedFlow<Unit>` that broadcasts "pings" from redis.

In `onMessage`, you could emit `Unit` into the mutable shared flow to notify subscribers, and then you can simply implement your request mechanism by awaiting the first element on the shared flow and making the `readSubset` request:

```kotlin
class AppMsgHandler(@Autowired private val appMsgRepo: AppMsgRepo) : MessageListener {

    private val events = MutableSharedFlow<Unit>()

    suspend fun requestMessages(start: Int, timeoutMillis: Long): List<AppMsg> {
        val currentMsgs = appMsgRepo.readSubset(start)
        if (currentMsgs.isNotEmpty()) {
            return currentMsgs
        }
        val newMessages = withTimeoutOrNull(timeoutMillis) {
            events.first()
            appMsgRepo.readSubset(start)
        }
        return newMessages ?: emptyList()
    }

    override fun onMessage(message: Message, pattern: ByteArray?) {
        LOG.info("RedisPub: {} on Channel: {}", String(message.body, UTF8), String(message.channel, UTF8))
        events.tryEmit(Unit)
    }

    companion object {
        private val LOG: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppMsgHandler::class.java)
        private val UTF8: Charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8
    }
}
```

The controller can then simply call `requestMessages` (provided you make your controller use `suspend` functions with Spring WebFlux).

Comment: I tried to use your code but somehow `events.tryEmit(Unit)` returns false when it waiting `events.first()`

Comment: Ah maybe you should add an `extraBufferCapacity` of 1 in the constructor of the state flow. I haven't looked at exactly how it works without suspension, but it might be because the consumer coroutine (waiting on `first()`) doesn't have a chance to take the value because the producer of the event doesn't suspend. Because there is no buffer, the producer would have no choice but to drop the event

Comment: Is it a good idea to wrap the onMessage with `coroutineScope.launch` so I can use emit instead of `tryEmit`

so It should be like this

```
override fun onMessage(message: Message, pattern: ByteArray?) {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            events.emit(Unit)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean my suggestion above didn't work? Did you try `MutableSharedFlow<Unit>(extraBufferCapacity = 1)`?
If that didn't work, it's probably a bad idea to start a coroutine there, because `onMessage` would then return immediately, which means it could be called again even though the coroutine is not done. This could generate a lot of coroutines that are potentially stuck if you don't solve the actual problem. An alternative would be to call the suspending `emit()` in `runBlocking` from `onMessage`, so at least you have backpressure